# Explanation of Sugar CRM's `field_arrays.php`

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

In SugarCRM, every code module with a bean has a `field_arrays.php` file.

```
ex. 
#File: modules/Accounts/field_arrays.php
```

These files define an array which is merged by code in the base `SugarBean` class, and appear to create four special designations for Bean columns

```
column_fields
list_fields
required_fields
export_fields
```

I've googled around, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer of what each of these designations are used for.  Does anyone here know?

I can easily speculate about some (`required_fields` seems pretty obvious), but I'd like to hear from someone who actually **knows** what a `column_field` is vs. a `list_field`, etc.

(Also, I realize that in day to day use these files are generated and I wouldn't need to worry about this — but I'm trying to understand the system from a programatic point of view)